How to change brightness of 2nd display in Windows-11 using powershell?
I would like to change the brightness of my 2nd display (connected to a laptop) using powershell. In fact there are no windows settings (I can find) that allow me to change the brightness of that display either, which is almost absurd, as I'm using the latest Windows-11 Pro.
How can I use powershell to set/change the screen brightness of my second display?

Have you tried the OSD for the monitor?

@Ramhound IDK what that is? Do you have a link?

Are you able to change the 2nd screen's brightness using any controls in the software, or can you only change it through the OSD menu?

Sorry, but what "software" are you referring to, and what is the "OSD menu"? (The answer is probably no.)
